# How to tell if my eclipse workspace is opened by another user?

Tags: eclipse, rhel

My workspace is saved on a shared drive. How can I tell if one of the people on my group has my workspace open?

Comment: You need to change your workflow, and to use a version control system such as git or mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse only supports one user at a time using a workspace. The workspace will be locked and you will get an error if you try and open it when someone else has it open.

Comment: Sometimes the .lock file does not delete properly. Does the ownership of the .lock file reflect who has it open?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't try to delete the lock file. It uses the Java `FileChannel.tryLock` method to do the lock - not sure exactly what that does to the ownership.